# Is there a benefit to leaving reviews on Expedia?

Tags: expedia, reviews

Is there a benefit to leaving reviews on Expedia? On travel.stackexchange.com answering questions that are upvoted will get you privileges and potentially badges as well.

On ebay.com leaving feedback might make the other person you're doing a transaction with more likely to leave you feedback, which bolsters your own rating. I.e. an eBay seller may be disinclined to leave feedback if they see that you've never left feedback yourself.

But on expedia, is there any benefit, be directly or indirectly?

Comment: The benefit is to the community, not to you personally.

Comment: Yup, it's that warm, fuzzy feeling that you get when you help others.

Comment: As opposed to the warm, fuzzy feeling that you get when you see your SE badges, reputation, and the ability to do moderator work for free.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Not really. The idea is that you'll leave feedback to help other travellers, as they most likely helped you too by leaving feedback, so you can avoid that dodgy hotel with bedbugs or that restaurant that gave you gastro.

The same is apparent with booking.com and other such sites.  It's a 'I'll help others and they'll help me' benefit.

Sometimes I've had some of these sites (especially booking.com) offer a reward for leaving a review - an entry into a draw, for example. And Google has tried gamifying it by having 'Local guide' points and levels, asking people to leave reviews, answer questions and add photos for points.

In terms of *direct* feedback, if negative, you *might* find an enthusiastic staff member at the hotel try to contact you after seeing the review to try and remedy it.

Comment: "In terms of direct feedback, if negative, you might find an enthusiastic staff member at the hotel try to contact you after seeing the review to try and remedy it." -> I always hope this happens, but it never does in my personal experience, even though I try to leave detailed and polite reviews if something went wrong.